# C++ error expected unqualified

Tags: c++

Okay so im trying to do some old quiz from my university and i have a question and this is the answer like this , when i try it on Dev-C++ its say wrong , but the teacher say its correct

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void add (int,int);
int substract(int,int);
int multiply(int,int);
void divide(int,int);
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    cout<<"Please Enter The Value of a: ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Please Enter The Value of b: ";
    cin>>b;
    add(a,b);
    cout<<"The substract a-b is: "<<substract(a,b)<<endl;
    cout<<"The multiply a*b is : "<<multiply(a,b)<<endl;
    divide(a,b);
    return 0;
}

void add (int a,int b);
{
    cout<<"There sum is: "<<a+b<<endl;
 }
int substract(int a,int b);
{
    return (a-b);
}
int multiply (int a,int b);
{
    return (a*b);
}
void divide (int a,int b);
{
    cout<<"There divide is: "<<a/b<<endl;
}
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: [Error] expected unqualified-id before "{" token

Comment: There shouldn't be semicolons in function definitions. They are only needed in function declarations. If your teacher looks at this closely and say it's correct, you have a very bad teacher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are placing semi colons at the end of your functions params list For example:

```
int substract(int a,int b); ---> (Should not have a semi-colon here)
{
    return (a-b);
}
```

Whenever C++ compiler throws an unexpected unqualified at you, it is usually in part because your semi-colons are incorrect. This is good to remember for debugging in the future!